# Не работает ссылка в блоке добавления изображений

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

Проявляется на ru.SO и на meta.ru.SO. На en.SO все работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Поправили!